# Query to retrive only Identity Columns in Teradata

Tags: t-sql, teradata

In Oracle DBA_SEQUENCES will retrieve all the sequences columns from each and every table.

Can you please tell me how can I find the same in Teradata?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identity information is stored in `dbc.idcol`, there's no Data Dictionary view on top of that, but it's easy to write:

```
SELECT
   d.DatabaseName
  ,t.tvmName AS TABLENAME
  ,c.FieldName
  ,id.AvailValue
  ,id.StartValue
  ,id.MINVALUE
  ,id.MAXVALUE
  ,id.INCREMENT
  ,id.cyc
FROM dbc.IdCol AS id
JOIN dbc.Dbase AS d
  ON id.DatabaseId = d.DatabaseId
JOIN dbc.tvm AS t
  ON id.TableId = t.tvmID
JOIN dbc.TVFields AS c
  ON c.TableId = id.TableID
WHERE c.IdColType IS  NOT NULL
;
```